# Amazon Web Services: Cloning instance and deploying on bigger instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am relatively new to Amazon Web Services and I am trying to find the best way to move my instance from a free to a paid tier instance, i.e. from t1.micro to m1.small.

My current infrastructure is as follows:

- 1x EC2 t1.micro - Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 64bit (with 1 EBS volume)
- 1x Micro RDS Instance

How can I clone my t1.micro instance along with the EBS backed volume and launch it in a m1.small instance?

Will this be a case of creating my own AMI of the instance and booting this on a new EC2 instance? If so, will creating this image create a snapshot of the EBS volume as well as my LAMP stack - my current Apache, PHP and MYSQL configurations?

Thanks in advance.

Lloyd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to resize your instance, cloning is not necessary. Just stop the instance, right-click on it, then choose "Change Instance Type". Choose your desired instance type and then start it back up.

Comment: An incredibly simple solution to my problem. Thanks!